# Is it legal to scan directories / sub-directories / files on some website?

Tags: scanning

I have a simply question about scanning websites.

Is it legal to scan directories / sub-directories / files on some website?

I know it's just sending request and read response, but can some website has problem with it?

Thanks.

Comment: The basic answer would be, if they would not want it, they would prevent it. As long as you don't interfere with the operation of that site, it'll be fine.

Comment: This would be a question more for the Law SE rather than superuser and legality would certainly depend on where you live.

Comment: What countries law, do you need to log in and is there a robots.txt file? The answer is very nuanced, but in general, if you dont need to log in and have not agreed otjerwise and you dont overwhelm the server  it would be "its legal". The behaviour you are describing matches that of a search engine, so outlawing this behavour wpild outlaw some common search engine functiomality

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and this doesn't constitute legal advice.*

> Is it legal to scan directories / sub-directories / files on some website?

If the information in those directories is intended to be accessed by the public, then it is likely legal. However, you cannot send a large amount of automated requests at once that interfere with other peoples use of the site (a [Denial-of-Service](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack).

If the information in those directories *isn't* intended to be accessed by the public (e.g. they are only available due to a security configuration error of some kind), then scanning those directories may not be legal (depending on the laws where you live).

> I know it's just sending request and read response, but can some website has problem with it?

Some websites may have an issue with you accessing information they would prefer you not, certainly, but assuming the access is legal (see above), all they can probably do is block your IP.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How large is a large amount of automated requests in req/sec?

Comment: Different websites can handle different amounts, so a "large amount" can vary. That said, if you emulate a normal user from a regular PC, you shouldn't approach anything close to a DoS attack. If you are using multiple machines (especially with smaller sites) you probably wish to be more careful. As a general guideline, just to put a number on it, a few requests a second probably should be fine. A bigger issue might simply be tripping any system they have in place to discourage automated scans by blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Anything readily available on a site, or more precisely; anything *linked* by it's pages. Can usually be considered "fair game".

**However** All this "content" are governed by what's generally called a **TOU** (Terms Of Use), or **TOS** (Terms Of Service). Which dictate their **usage** terms, which may well include their **access**. These terms (even if stated *separately*) can/should be considered a **License** (of use).

In other words; look for these *before* attempting *access*. They will answer your question *directly*.